# Python dataframe interaction

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I have the following dataframe:

```
topic  student level week
1      a       1     1
1      b       2     1
1      a       3     1
2      a       1     2
2      b       2     2
2      a       3     2
2      b       4     2
```

The new dataframe should represent an interaction between students through the topic. It should contain four columns: "*student source*", "*student destination*", "*week*" and "*reply count*".

*Student Destination* is a student that each student shared the topic with.

*Reply count* is a number of times in which  *Student Destination* "directly" replied to *Student Source*.

The new dataframe should look like:

```
st_source st_dest  week  reply_count
    a        b       1        1
    a        b       2        2
    b        a       1        1
    b        a       2        1
```

*Reply count* can be explained easier with an example.

If a thread is started by student A (by sending a message at level 1), B replied to A (sending a message at level 2), C replied to B (sending a message at level 3). Then B "directly" replied to A, and C "directly" replied to
B, but C's reply to A *is not direct* (and so we don't count it).

Does anyone have some idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything? This looks like a homework problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = (df.groupby('week').apply(
        lambda g: g.groupby([g.student.shift(), g.student])
        .week.agg({'reply_count': 'count'})
        .rename_axis(("st_source", "st_dest"))
    ).reset_index())
​
result[['st_source', 'st_dest', 'week', 'reply_count']].sort_values(['st_source', 'st_dest'])

# st_source     st_dest   week  reply_count
#0        a         b        1          1
#2        a         b        2          2
#1        b         a        1          1
#3        b         a        2          1
```

Comment: Thanks @Psidom for your suggestion! I have a slightly different solution. Student Source and Destination are the same person. Maybe because I have more students than given in the example.